# Blackbox SQLi: MySql “error in your SQL syntax” when larger “UNSIGNED BIGINT”

Tags: mysql, security, sql-injection

I'm trying to blackbox pentest a website, the URL has the form http://example.com/a/[integer_value]/something_else

When trying to change [integer_value] to quotes (double and single), characters. It does not have any affect. But, when the [integer_value] larger than UNSIGNED BIGTINT, there'll be an SQL error throwed. That's to say:

1. if 0 <= [integer_value] <= ( UNSIGNED BIGTINT, which is 2^64-1) => no error
2. if [integer_value] > UNSIGNED BIGTINT => error: e.g. "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '18446744073709551616' at line 1"

Any ideas ?

Is this exploitable ?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not exploitable directly, **if**

1. it is truly the only scenario where an incoming request can induce your MySQL server to throw an error, **and**
2. the web site only performs side-effect-free SELECT operations in response to those URLs.

But, those are big *if*s. When you're doing blackbox testing, in principle you cannot know whether they are true.

Plus, when your system throws the error it reveals information about the way the website works. That's not wise on the *dirty wire*, also known as the *public internet*.

You're much better off doing some sanity checking of these values before you hand them to your MySQL server. For example, you could attempt to  convert the incoming string to a 64-bit number. If the conversion fails, you can stop there.  Or, you could check the number of digits in the number and reject numbers that are longer than your application requires.

Your website shoud respond to this kind of URL with a simple `404 not found`, just as it would to any other requested URL that it cannot process.

You're not paranoid. Highy motivated and very clever criminals are working hard to pwn your web site.

Comment: I agree. Those are big ifs. For now, I just find that only subtle error.